# How can i type this scroll event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

Hi i'm making an infinite scroll event to trigger new fetch on React Query, the problem is that i can't find a way to type this on typescript

```
function onScroll(this: Document, ev: ScrollBehavior<EventListener>) {
  const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = ev.target.scrollingElement;

  if (hasNextPage && scrollHeight - scrollTop <= clientHeight * 1.2) {
    fetchNextPage();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see you using `this` anywhere. Why would you type it?

Comment: because i'm getting this error on vscode `Property 'scrollingElement' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`

Comment: It has nothing to do with `this`. You wrongly typed your `ev`

Comment: ok, but the problem still the event type `this` type was only a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.target` will never be `document`, you have to access `document` directly

```
function onScroll() {
  const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = document.scrollingElement;

  if (hasNextPage && scrollHeight - scrollTop <= clientHeight * 1.2) {
    fetchNextPage();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are searching for this, the solution was to type event.target as Document like this:

```
function onScroll(ev: Event) {
      const target = ev.target as Document;
      const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = target.scrollingElement;

      if (hasNextPage && scrollHeight - scrollTop <= clientHeight * 1.2) {
        fetchNextPage();
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    };
```